# Fastest way to update orderning in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting

Say I have a list of items, all generated from a database. For the sake of this example, let's call them:

```
item1
item2
item3
...
itemN
```

Say I want to allow someone to drag any of these items and place them in the order they want (i.e. they can take item10 and place it between item2 and item3, so that it now shows up after item2).

This means that I need to update the ordering of all items that are after where the dragged item was placed. What is the most efficient way of doing this? Is there a trick or am I just updating everything after?

EDIT:

Would a node-approach be faster?\ By node, I mean each item is linked to the next item. This way, you only need to update three nodes' children and then everything else would properly work. So in my example above, before drag I had :

`item2.child = item3`, `itemN-1.child = itemN`, `itemN.child = null`.

After drag, I would need to update:

`item2.child = itemN`, `itemN.child = item3`, `itemN-1.child = null`

Is this a better implementation? Doing this, I can't figure out a way to then display a list of queries from the db properly ...

Comment: I just update every row (even if only two exchanged places), but I wonder this as well. Seems like the extra effort to minimize the updates in your server-side code isn't worth it, but maybe there's another approach. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP in Laravel Framework. But as you said it, I am more interested in the logic, rather than the actual code implementation.

Comment: There are whole tutorials written on this stuff e.g. http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/

Comment: No no, I mean the database update, not the UI view

Comment: **What are these 'items', and what is their order meant to represent?** Do they need to be ordered? Is date-rodering, which is relatively easy, sufficient?

Comment: You actually need to run a bulk of `SQL` queries. There is no way to achieve that via single one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your talking a UI way here is:

Say we have 5 elements names each element has a attr called "order"

```
<ob1 order="1" name="1">
<ob1 order="2" name="2">
<ob1 order="3" name="3">
<ob1 order="4" name="4">
<ob1 order="5" name="5">
```

Say we want to put the one with the name of "5" into first place.

It becomes:

```
<ob1 order="1" name="5">
<ob1 order="2" name="1">
<ob1 order="3" name="2">
<ob1 order="4" name="3">
<ob1 order="5" name="4">
```

When you drag name="5" to the top the order gets set to 1 then the rest get 1 added to them.

Alternatively:

Say we have 5 elements names each element has a attr called "order"

```
<ob1 order="1" name="1">
<ob1 order="2" name="2">
<ob1 order="3" name="3">
<ob1 order="4" name="4">
<ob1 order="5" name="5">
```

When you move name="5" to the top it gets the next elements sort order then subtracts 1 from it so:

It becomes:

```
<ob1 order="0" name="5">
<ob1 order="1" name="1">
<ob1 order="2" name="2">
<ob1 order="3" name="3">
<ob1 order="4" name="4">
```

Applying the same type again lets move 4 to the top:

```
<ob1 order="-1" name="4">
<ob1 order="0" name="5">
<ob1 order="1" name="1">
<ob1 order="2" name="2">
<ob1 order="3" name="3">
```

Sorry for a wall of text.

The fastest way of moving them around the database: There isnt one. Handle the sorting in your code then apply the sorting to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i am talking more about the database update, and not the UI.

Comment: That's in there too :) Very last part.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you're interested in actual logic here is the idea that I have implemented few months ago:

- For the UI, delay any server-side request as long as possible
- When you send the ordering request, format the data as `id => order`. Most optimal way.
- **Activate transactions**
- Fetch all the data (possibly indexed by an `id` field)
- Based on the `POST` and the fetch data calculate the `delta`, that is, what has and what has not changed. *This can greatly reduce number of queries to run.*
- Run as many `UPDATE` queries as necessary
- **Commit the transaction.**

**Conclusion**: I can't think of an optimal way to do it, mainly because of the nature of `SQL`'s `UPDATE` query